# plotting without axis and bonding box in matlab / octave

Tags: matlab, plot, octave

I have two plots below.  How can I get rid of the axis and the bonding box on the second plot?
I'm using octave 3.8.1

Plot command I use to create plots.

```
clf(figure(1))
figure (1);
plot(xfreq_orig(1:3000),yamp_orig(1:3000)); 
print ('-dpng','-S1024,768', strcat('/tmp/','01_graph.png')); %export plot to file

hold on;

clf(figure(2))
figure (2);
plot(xfreq_orig(1:3000),yamp_inv(1:3000),'r')
print ('-dpng','-S1024,768', strcat('/tmp/','02_graph.png')); %export plot
```

[image: 1st plot]

[image: 2nd plot]

Comment: if you want the axis but not the box: `set(gca, 'box', 'off')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's as simple as

```
axis off
```

You could also try

```
box off
```

which just disable some parts of the axis border

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not work with polar plots in Octave 5.1. Does anybody know a workaround?